# Perspective text in a circle - Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, perspective

I'd like to recreate the "text in a circle" effect shown in the image with Adobe Illustrator

[image]

Which tool should I use?

Comment: This question shows zero effort and is vague.. which type? The type around the circumference or the inner type? What have you tried? Where is it failing?.. I'm amazed this question is getting up votes

Answer (score 4):

I made some tests to achieve the best result.

Here I show the images with the tests I did in IllustratorCC2015 and CorelDrawX3(in this case I had no good results).

I just got the best when I sliced the top shape to the character width and applied the envelope separately. But it needs a little tweaking.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is tagged Adobe Illustrator, yes this can be done in Illustrator, but be advised this is not a 'click-here-and-this-happens' or 'text-in-a-circle' effect. This is most likely a hand customized typo and with every letter adjusted manually.